# mySQL NATURAL JOIN to show results similar to LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, join

I have the following mySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `objects`
natural join `gPeople`
natural join `gVip`
natural join `gTeachers`
```

Which returns:

```
object_id       name            vip_code           subject
----------------------------------------------------------
003             John            9003               Math
```

This is because 'John' is in the groups People, Vip and Teachers.

I have other people in just two groups and would like them to show like:

```
object_id       name            vip_code           subject
----------------------------------------------------------
001             Mary                               History
002             Holly           9002               
003             John            9003               Math
```

I have tried left outer joins but I end up with many copies of the objects_id column which is not desired due to the way I use the results.

Note: I must use * as it is the core of what I am trying to do. I need the tables to be able to support columns being added/removed and the query able to pick them up.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eefe7/3/0 this is the SQL Fiddle of what I have tried however my result looks like this:

```
object_id   object_id   name      object_id   vip_code     object_id   subject
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
001         001         Mary                               001         History
002         002         Holly     002         9002                            
003         003         John      003         9003         003         Math
```

Anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Quote: "I have tried left outer joins"

Comment: A better response would have been to post some code

Comment: @Craig Could you please post some table structures? If possible, use SQL Fiddle.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eefe7/3/0 here is the SQL Fiddle however the result is not what I get. I will edit the post in a sec to show the result I get.

Comment: Ok added the result I am getting which differs from SQL Fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by editing the result in PHP.

```
$sql = "SELECT `o`.`object_id` AS `ID`, `gP`.*, `gV`.*, `gT`.* FROM `objects` `o`
left outer join `gPeople` `gP` ON `o`.`object_id` = `gP`.`object_id`
left outer join `gVip` `gV` ON `o`.`object_id` = `gV`.`object_id`
left outer join `gTeachers` `gT` ON `o`.`object_id` = `gT`.`object_id`";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $row->object_id = $row->ID;
    unset($row->ID);
}
```

This results in:

```
object_id       name            vip_code           subject
----------------------------------------------------------
001             Mary                               History
002             Holly           9002               
003             John            9003               Math
```

Instead of:

```
object_id       name            vip_code           subject
----------------------------------------------------------
001             Mary                               History
                Holly           9002               
003             John            9003               Math
```

It seems that because there is no object_id in the table gSubject for object 002 it overwrites the object_id in the result with a null value.

i.e. For object 002 on the first pass (objects table) it equals 002 then on the second pass (gPeople table) it is overwritten again with 002 then on the third pass (gVip Table) it is overwritten again with 002 then on the last pass (gTeachers table) it is overwritten with null as there is no record in the table for it.